# how would I keep spawning an SKSpriteNode in random locations on the right side of the screen to translate it from the this random location the left?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am not sure how to go about doing this. The code below is supposed to move the ball from the right side of the screen to the left, remove the ball and then spawn another. However it is not working as the ball does nothing (By the way I am using swift 4)

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let Ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    moveBall()

}

func moveBall() {


    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 0)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: -300, y: 0)

    let moveToEndAction = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 2)
    let atEndAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let resetTostartAction = SKAction.move(to: startPoint, duration: 0)

    let moveToEndThenStartAgain = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveToEndAction, atEndAction, resetTostartAction]))

Ball.run(SKAction.repeatForever(moveToEndThenStartAgain))

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based off how I have interpreted the tough wording and lack of code for your question, this is what I have come up with.

You want to create the object that you are moving. I'm assuming you have created a class for this (then again, I don't know because you didn't give any information). So if you do have a class, follow these guidelines:

```
let object = Object()   

//wherever you decide to start your object
let randomStartX = randomCGFloat(min: randomVal, max: randomVal)
let randomStartY = randomCGFloat(min: randomVal, max: randomVal)
object.position = CGPoint(x: randomStartX, y: randomStartY)
self.addChild(object)
```

The random start and end positions will be specific to the range of where you want the object to start and end. That is for you to figure out and play with.

Now to move the object, you will want to create a new function. Let's say `spawnNewObject()`. In this function you will want to use SKActions in order to move the object to the end location. The speed will be whatever you want it to be.

```
func spawnNewObject(){

    let randomEndX = randomCGFloat(min: randomVal, max: randomVal)
    let randomEndY = randomCGFloat(min: randomVal, max: randomVal)

    let move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: randomEndX, y: randomEndY), duration: speed)
    object.run(sequence)
}
```

Now, if you want to remove the object whenever it reaches its end point, update the function to this:

```
func spawnNewObject(){

    let randomEndX = randomCGFloat(min: randomVal, max: randomVal)
    let randomEndY = randomCGFloat(min: randomVal, max: randomVal)

    let move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: randomEndX, y: randomEndY), duration: speed)
    let removeFromParent = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move,removeFromParent])
    object.run(sequence)
}
```

Comment: @user10101053 I have made a game in which I have used this technique. The tricky part is figuring out the values for the start and end. I am unsure of the intended movement of your objects, therefore it is hard to give you more specifics